# Como fazer um temporizador simples utilizando TimeUnit.sleep

Tags: java, swing, timer

Eu sou iniciante em `Java` e estava tentando fazer um joguinho matemático cuja temática era somar os números aleatorios dos botões (claro q a pessoa teria a ajuda dos números 1, 2 e 5) ate chegar a um valor igual ao numero randômico gerado automaticamente (melhor que uma simples calculadora).

A única coisa que sinto falta, ate o momento, é de um `timer` para dar mais um nível de dificuldade ao jogo. Contudo, eu tentei fazer um simples temporizador para testar se dava pra fazer com `TimeUnit.Sleep` e não deu muito certo.

No caso, a `Jlabel` `lblGameTime` pegaria o valor dos segundos (60) e iria decaindo 1 a cada segundo com o jogo aberto, caso a pessoa conseguisse igualar `valorSomado` com `valorRandomico`, o programa randomizaria o valor dos Botões e `valorRandomico` novamente e o tempo iria ter mais 30 segundos adicionais (mas esta ideia é de outro método que ainda vou fazer, Só citei para complementar a pergunta)

```
public void GameTime() {
    int seconds = 60;
        for (int i = seconds; i < 0; i++) {
            lblGameTime.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(tela1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

variavel `valorSomado`:

```
private int valorSomado = 0;
```

Metodo `valorRandomico`:

```
private long randomNumber() {
    long ale;
    ale = (long) ((Math.random()) * (10001 - 0) + 1);
    lblRandomNumber.setText(String.valueOf(ale));
    return ale;
}
```

PS: O "`Swing`" que estou usando é aquele do `NetBeans` que já vem com uma tela separada onde da pra modelar toda a tela no qual o código será executado

[image: imagem do tal "<code>Swing</code>" do <code>NetBeans</code>]

PSS: Tive a "brilhante" ideia de tentar não usar classes (mesmo sabendo q eu estou usando `Java` )

[image: descrição mal feita]

Comment: Apenas pra fins informativos, o `swing` é uma API do java, não do netbeans. Aquilo que você vê que constrói telas no estilo *drag 'n drop* é o GUI builder, que usa o swing diretamente do JDK.

Comment: Obrigado por me falar isso @DiegoF, mais uma coisa pra memorizar, hehe

Comment: Se não me engano, Existe uma classe Timer no swing, só não me lembro como usá-la. Quando puder, caso ninguém tenha respondido, eu tento responder algo.

Comment: vou dar uma olhada nessa classe @DiegoF, obrigado novamente